# How to make on click listener items in fragment and reflect in another fragment

Tags: android

I want to click on particular button in listitems in fragment A  and then particular item should be reflected into fragment B.

When I click on particular button of particular item then that item should be reflect in fragment B.
When I click on button in front of ram then ram should be reflect in fragment B

and when I click on button in front of Holly then Holly should be reflect in fragment B.
for this what should I do?

here is my code:

**Class A**

```
public class A extends ListFragment {

    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    Context mContext;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list;

    SimpleAdapter adapter;
    String[] names = new String[] { "Ram", "Abhi", "Rohit", "Holly", "James",
            "Hana", "Jack", "Ram" };
    Integer[] imageId = new Integer[] { R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher,

    };

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        List<HashMap<String, String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
            hm.put("txt", "   " + names[i]);
            hm.put("flag", Integer.toString(imageId[i]));
            aList.add(hm);
        }

        String[] from = { "flag", "txt" };

        int[] to = { R.id.flag, R.id.txt };

        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity()
                .getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.listitems, from, to);

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    }
}
```

**Class B**

```
public class B extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View V = inflater.inflate(R.layout.b, container, false);

    return V;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus).

When you click on Button in Fragment-A, Post event.

Now Fragment-B is Listening that event, so whenever you are post event Fragment-B will be get notify about it.

**Example**

1. Dependency:

   If you are using eclipse then download jar file from [here](https://greenrobot.github.io/EventBus/) If you are using Android Studio then add dependency

   ```
   compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
   ```
2. Define event:

   public class MessageEvent {

   ```
   private final int position;

   /* Additional fields if needed */
   public MessageEvent(int position) {
       this.position = position;
   }

   public int getPosition() {
       return position;
   }
   ```

   }
3. Prepare subscriber:

   Fragment in which you get Event notification.

   ```
   public class FragmentB extends Fragment {
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
   }

   @Override
   public void onDestroy() {
       super.onDestroy();
       EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
   }

   public void onEventMainThread(MessageEvent event) {
       // put your code here for update list item  
       event.getPosition();
       // you can also add extra other field in MessageEvent
   }
   ```

   }
4. Post event:

   In your Fragment-A whenever you want to notify

   ```
   EventBus.getDefault().post(new MessageEvent(ITEM_POSITION));
   ```

Comment: i didn't understand so would you please implement and post your answwer her

Answer (score 0):

Handle the listview`s setOnItemClickListener on fragment A and pass the value as an extra in the bundle to fragment B.

Answer (score 0):

Add an interface in Fragment A and implement the interface in Fragment B. Based on the values passed in callback method, do appropriate change in Fragment B.